# Counting button clicks with PHP

Tags: php

Just trying to count the number of times a button has been clicked, record that to a file so it works for everyone. It's reading the file, but ain't writing. Ideas?

```
        <form action='' method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Tweet it!" onclick="genTweet()"/>
    </form>

    <br>


    <?php
        $f = fopen('counter.txt', 'r+'); // use 'r+' instead
        flock($f, LOCK_EX); // avoid race conditions with concurrent requests
        $total = (int) fread($f, max(1, filesize('counter.txt'))); // arg can't be 0
        /*if someone has clicked submit*/
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
           rewind($f); // move pointer to start of file so we overwrite instead of append
           fwrite($f, ++$total);
        }
        fclose($f);
    ?>

    This button has been clicked <?php echo $total; ?> times.
```

Comment: I would avoid using a file for this.  I would switch to a database solution.  If 2 people click the button at the same time there could discrepancies.

Comment: Check to make sure the file has proper writing permissions. Usually 644 will do, but as a last resort, try 777. 777 is not recommended though, but you can try both.

Comment: @QuinnFTW Although I agree on using a DB, OP is using file locking `LOCK_EX`.

Comment: I did check permissions and they are set to 777

Answer (score 0):

if you are using PHP version above 5.3.2 you should call flock with LOCK_UN flag. fclose might not be enough to release the lock until the processing owning it will remain alive.

The [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) man page states:

> On versions of PHP before 5.3.2, the lock is released also by fclose() (which is also called automatically when script finished).

Also check counter.txt file permission. It must be writable by the web server user.

```
<?php
$total = 0;
$f = @fopen('counter.txt', 'r+');
if ($f) {
  $mode = (isset($_POST["submit"]) ? LOCK_EX : LOCK_SH);
  if (flock($f, $mode)) {
    $total = (int)fgets($f);
    if ($mode == LOCK_EX) {
      ftruncate($f, 0);
      fputs($f, ++current);
      fflush($f);
    }
    flock($f, LOCK_UN);
  }
  fclose($f);
}
else {
  print "counter.txt could not be opened";
}
?>
```

Comment: that gives me an error Request URL:  http://localhost:8888/science_stands/
Request Method:  GET
Status Code:  HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error